# excel 2007 unhide sheets

Tags: excel

in excel 2007 I have a spread sheet that has hidden sheets. I know all the passwords. To unhide sheets I'm supposed to right click on sheet name tabs on the bottom and click unhide. However the unhide option is greyed out.

the hide - unhide under Home > Format is also greyed out.

I have a password for the whole sheet, but I don't know where to enter it.

I hate excel 2007 ribbon structure.

Comment: Your Excel version is legal, I presume? You can save and modify the document or any other, for example?

Comment: yes, of course. it's only this one workbook

Answer (score 6):

I figured out the Answer and it is:

Ribbon > Review > Protect Workbook
Unclick - Protect Structure and Structure
Enter the password and the menu items are enabled

Thanks everyone for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you hide the sheets yourself or did someone else do it?

It's possible the sheets are "very hidden"; see [this link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=240252) for more information.  You may have to use ALT+F11 to go into the Visual Basic Editor and change the sheet's Visible property.

Comment: the sheets are hidden in vba as well. I had once found where to enter the WorkBook (whole spreadsheet) unprotect password, but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
for each worksheet ws in activeworkbook
begin
  ws.visible = true
end
```

Correct the syntax if need be, but the above VBA should unhide all hidden worksheets.